# typoscript issue with LOAD_REGISTER and if condition to fill a list

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase

What I'm trying to do is quite complex and an Extbase extension is involved...

Step by step, what I'm trying to do:

- An Extbase plugin decides, if certain navigation elements should be marked.
- This plugin has one action for each navigation element.
- The returned value (0 or 1) from each action in TS is stored on the stack (LOAD_REGISTER).
- A list of page UIDs is build by checking against the stored values (0,1).
- The navigation COA is modified using this list of page UIDs.

Here is the typoscript code I'm using:

```
// load information, if pages lack info, into register
10 = LOAD_REGISTER
10 {
  lacksAnfahrt {
    cObject = USER_INT
    cObject {
      userFunc = tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run
      pluginName = Pa_klinik_data_edit
      extensionName = Hplusinfo
      controller = SpitalInfoPA
      switchableControllerActions {
        SpitalInfoPA {
          1 = completeAnfahrt
        }
      }
    }
  }

  lacksAktivitaeten < .lacksAnfahrt
  lacksAktivitaeten.cObject.switchableControllerActions.SpitalInfoPA.1 = completeAktivitaeten

  lacksBildergalerie < .lacksAnfahrt
  lacksBildergalerie.cObject.switchableControllerActions.SpitalInfoPA.1 = completeBildergalerie

  // build a list of PIDs that are going to be marked in navigation
  lackPIDs.cObject = COA
  lackPIDs.cObject {
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
      value = {$config.PIDLists.anfahrt},
      if {
        value = 1
        equals.data = register:lacksAnfahrt
      }
    }

    20 < .10
    20.value = {$config.PIDLists.bildergalerie},
    20.if.equals.data = register:lacksBildergalerie

    30 < .10
    30.value = {$config.PIDLists.aktivitaeten},
    30.if.equals.data = register:lacksAktivitaeten

    // don't let the comma separated list end with a comma
    99 = TEXT
    99.value = 0
  } // lackPIDs
} // REGISTER

// mark incomplete pages with a red exclamation mark
20 {  // = HMENU
  1 {  // = TMENU
    NO {  // = 1
      stdWrap.wrap = |<span class="warning lacksInfo">!</span>
      stdWrap.wrap.if {
        value.data = register:lackPIDs
        isInList.field = uid
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If i print out `register:lacksBildergalerie` and all the others, their values are correct (0 or 1).
But the `lackPIDs`list always **empty** (except of the 0 at the end)... There must be something wrong with the middle part:

```
10 {
  value = {$nav.PIDLists.anfahrt},
  if {
    value = 1
    equals.data = register:lacksAnfahrt
  }
}
```

This evaluation seams to return *false* in any case.

I also tried with different *if* function like:

```
10 {
  value = {$nav.PIDLists.anfahrt},
  if {
    isTrue.data = register:lacksAnfahrt
  }
}
```

But this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: did you ever figured this out, I just asked something very similar [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/q/40145253/5353105) ...

Answer (score 0):

Just overlooked that the other registers are using USER_INT as well

Comment: Hi, I started without _INT and it didn't work neither. Could it also be an issue that the actions are configured as non cacheable in Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension::configurePlugin?