# typoscript: do not show submenu if certain backend_layout is selected

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I made a special panning sub menu with icons which can be inserted choosing a specific backend_layout named **pagets__panmenu** , if that layout is selected the main menu should not display a sub menu and link to the page instead of opening a sub ...

I work with typo3 V7.6.11 and fluid styled content

The part reading the value works correctly:

```
NO = 1
NO {
  before.cObject = LOAD_REGISTER
  before.cObject{
    panmenu.cObject = TEXT
    panmenu.cObject.data.dataWrap = DB:pages:{field:uid}:backend_layout
  }
  ATagBeforeWrap = 1
  wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
  stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
}
```

This is my best effort to match, but its not working:

```
IFSUB <.NO
IFSUB {
    wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown">|</li>
    wrapItemAndSub.override = <li>|</li>        
    wrapItemAndSub.override.if {
        value.data = register:panmenu
        equals = pagets__panmenu
    }

    ATagParams = class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
    ATagBeforeWrap = 1
}
```

I know that also the 2 < .1 has to be suppressed, I'm trying to get the **if** to work to keep the style and link clean for starters ...

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614470/typoscript-condition-backend-layout-with-slide perhaps this helps

Comment: @bschauer thanks for the effort, but I fail to see the pertinence (I'm really a beginner here) I go by trial and error until it goes, I think my syntax is almost right ... (i can output `{register:panmenu}`) in a wrap so I just need to match it somehow ...

Answer (score 1):

First of all: have you set `TMENU.IFSUB = 1`?
Else, everything you do in `IFSUB` won't have an effect.

Now some general thoughts:

a) Normally, backend layouts are used to switch an entire page template:

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
  file.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
  file.stdWrap.cObject {
    key.data = pagelayout

    default = TEXT
    default.value = {$myTemplatePath}/Standard.html

    1 = TEXT
    1.value = {$myTemplatePath}/Home.html

    2 = TEXT
    2.value = {$myTemplatePath}/Landing.html

  }
  layoutRootPath = {$myLayoutPath}
  partialRootPath = {$myPartialPath}
}
```

So this initiates the frontend rendering for the entire page, where backend_layout with uid 1 will use the `Home.html` template, backend_layout with uid 2 will use the `Landing.html` template, and all others (=default) will use the `Standard.html` template.

If you build your site by this method, I would recommend doing

```
# that's the original version of your menu
lib.panmenu = HMENU
lib.panmenu {
 // ...
}

# make a copy of the original 
lib.panmenu_variant < lib.panmenu
# modify it as required 
lib.panmenu_variant.1.NO {   
  // ... 
}
```

Now, in your page Templates (which you call separately via the `CASE` from above), you can either use

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.panmenu" />
```

or

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.panmenu_variant" />
```

b) But if you don't want to follow that approach, you should also be able to use the backend_layout `CASE` on any `cObject`.  The `CASE` variant has proven much more robust for me.

Here' how I'd try to get the CASE working (untested!)

```
// suppose temp.navigation_main is your full menu
temp.navigation_main_variant < temp.navigation_main 
temp.navigation_main_variant {
    // modify the menu as you please
    10.2 >
    10.1.IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
}

// use lib.nav in your page
lib.nav = CASE
lib.nav {
    key.data = pagelayout
    // normally, lib.nav is the full navigation
    default < lib.navigation_main
    // except if be layout 1 is selected
    1 < lib.navigation_main_variant
  }
}
```

c) I've tried TypoScript constructions with `LOAD_REGISTER` and `if`s years ago and they always made me go crazy. I wouldn't invest too much energy into them, as  they rather seem to be legacy parameters than the future way of development for TYPO3 logic.

Comment: all correct but I knew this, the trouble is that the menu behaviour can be written correctly only by taking the choise of be-layout since it is an option ... I've seen the if case used many times, is it possible there is no correct syntax for this?

Comment: how would the CASE be implemented ?

Comment: Did you check if `TMENU.IFSUB` is set?

Comment: probably the syntax is just so counter-intuitive it is hard to reproduce & adapt

Comment: I tried to keep the snippets concise... [here](http://newred.ch/syntax/lib.navigation.main.php) is the whole voice and what I last tried (a modified `lib.navigation.main` for `EXT:t3sbootstrap`)

Comment: had to startup, yes TMENU.IFSUB is set (i do get the submenu, disregarding the condition) now that you look closer you agree that I'll have to find a solution in this ... in fluid etc. I could not differentiate for the main menu ...

Comment: I didn't mean your code with counterintuitive, but the "load_register" stuff :-)

Comment: but I'm sorry, it's too complicated for me to be of help. but again: if you query for be_layout, why can't you use the approach with two different submenu configs based on a CASE for the selected be_layout? or would you like me to try to make an example for that?

Comment: Yes please, an example of that would be great, I'm not familiar with the use of `CASE` ... you might want to do that as a seperate answer so that I could elect it as the solving one ... (if one is allowed to give more than 1 answer)

Comment: I've added my approach above. It's untested, but you should see what I mean

Comment: You don't have to stick to `pagelayout` with the `CASE` if you'd prefer another field. Also, here's a nice tutorial (in german) on all kinds of conditions http://de.slideshare.net/einpraegsam/typo3-typoscript-if-case-conditions